# hook_install and node_add_body_field do not work

Tags: nodes

I am making a custom module for a website.  Part of what my module does is create fields and around seven different content types. I have pasted the code from my module files bellow.  The module name is edu2_contenttypes.  The problem is that after enabling the module, the created content types only have the title field. The location type must have a body field as well as a edu2_contenttypes_locationid.  But it only has the title.  I put a bunch of dpms in the hook_install and found that the function is never called.  The spelling is correct and consistent with my edu2_contenttypes.module file.  So I don't know what is going on. Please help!

**edu2_contenttypes.install**

```
    $sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = location';
    for($i =1 ; $i < count($types); ++$i) $sql .= ' OR n.types = ' . $types[$i];
    $result = db_query($sql);
    $nodeids = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $nodeids[] = $row->nid;
    }
    node_delete_multiple($nodeids);
    dpm($types) ;
    foreach ($types as $key) {
      dpm($key);
      node_type_delete($key);
    }
}

function _edu2_contenttypes_installed_fields(){
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'edu2_contenttypes_location_id' => array(
      'field_name' => $t('edu2_contenttypes_location'),
      'label' => $t('location'),
      'type' => 'text'
    )
  );
}

function _edu2_contenttypes_installed_instances(){
  $t = get_t() ;
  return array(
    'edu2_contenttypes_location_id' => array(
      'field_name' => 'edu2_contenttypes_location_id',
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => $t('location instance'),
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'text_textfield'
      ),
      'display' => array(
        'example_node_list' => array(
          'label' => $t('locaton of the product'),
          'type' => 'text'
        )
      )
    )
  );
}

function add_custom_fields(){
  foreach (_edu2_contenttypes_installed_fields() as $field) {
        field_create_field($field);
    }
    foreach (_edu2_contenttypes_installed_instances() as $fieldinstance) {
        $fieldinstance['entity_type'] = 'node';
        $fieldinstance['bundle'] = 'location';
        print_r($fieldinstance);
        field_create_instance($fieldinstance);
    }
}
```

**edu2_contenttypes.module**

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_node_info()
*/


function edu2_contenttypes_node_info(){
  return array(
    'location' => array(
      'name' => t('location'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('survey location'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('location name')
    ),
    'organism' => array(
      'name' => t('organism'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('organism'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('organism name')
    ),
    'school' => array(
      'name' => t('school'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('school'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('school name')
    ),
    'session' => array(
      'name' => t('session'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('session'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('session date')
    ),
    'stress' => array(
      'name' => t('stress'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('stress'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('stress name')
    ),
    'substrate' => array(
      'name' => t('substrate'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('substrate'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('substrate name')
    ),
    'intersect' => array(
      'name' => t('intersect'),
      'base' => 'edu2_contenttypes',
      'description' => t('intersect'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('intersect number')
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Implements hook_form()
*/
function edu2_contenttypes_form($node, $formstate){
  return node_content_form($node, $formstate);
}
```